# Java Socket vs. C# TcpClient

Tags: c#, java, sockets, tcpclient

I am converting a Java application into C# and I have a general question regarding the underlying stream of bytes.

A 'byte' is unsigned in C# as opposed to signed in Java.

What does this do to parts of my code where I am comparing bytes for equivalency. For example:

Java code

```
public final static byte IAC = (byte)255;
...
void parseBuffer(byte[] bb, int len) {
    try {
        for(int i = 0;i < len; i++) {
            if(bb[i] == IAC)
                DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to do anything to the declaration of the IAC variable? Would it be anything other then (byte)255?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to do anything to the declaration of the IAC variable?

No. It's absolutely fine. You'll end up with a value of -1 for IAC, but that's fine and still represents a byte with all bits set. If you send a byte of value 255 from the C# side, it will be picked up correctly on the Java side.

Another alternative would be to work with a larger data type (e.g. `int` for convenience, and use bitmasking to end up with a value in the range [0, 255]:

```
public static final int IAC = 255;
...
void parseBuffer(byte[] bb, int len) {
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int value = bb[i] & 0xff; // To get a value in the range [0, 255]
            if (value == IAC) {
                DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. A quick follow up to your response. Are you saying that when reading the stream of bytes from TcpClient it will be reading byte values that are unsigned so comparing them to other unsigned bytes like my declaration for IAC is ok and will be semantically the same as the Java version?

Comment: @user1137939: The bytes are just bytes - 8 bit values. In C# a `byte` value with all 8 bits set has a numeric value of 255, whereas in Java it has a numeric value of -1. It's unfortunate (you almost *never* actually want to treat bytes as signed values) but you should be fine. Just try to keep thinking of them as collections of 8 bits instead of numbers - it'll make your life easier :)